# How to get the url and title of a tab in safari?

Tags: html, url, safari, safari-extension

I am building a extension for safari and for that I need to get the url and the title of the page everytime the tab is loaded. and after getting the url and title I want to display it in the extension popover as

```
URL = ...........................;
Titlt = .........................;
```

So how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I read

"the global file and extension bars have access to the SafariApplication, SafariBrowserWindow, and SafariBrowserTab classes, whose methods and properties allow you to work with windows and tabs."

"The SafariBrowserTab class allows you to identify a tab’s parent browser window, get and set the URL associated with a tab..." [Safari Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW4)

Here's the SafariBrowserTab class reference, for reference: [Getting Information About Browser Tabs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserTabClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009793-CH1-SW2)

Neither give a code example, so here's (an untested) one, in the global file or extension bar.

```
var title = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title;
```

You can then go on to use `title` in the popover.